# SSIS Foreach Loop Datasource

Tags: foreach, ssis, connection-string

I am trying to apply a sql query on different databases on several servers but I have an error when thrying to connect with dynamic connection manager datasource. Workflow :

[image: Query different Server/Databases]

I am able to iterate through the foreach but I am not able to apply the query to all the Server/DB configurations.
I am using a dynamic datasource set by variable in an expression.
My connection string is strctured like this : `Data Source=SrvName;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Initial Catalog=DB1;User Id=Usr;Password=Pwd;`

My "Source" in connection manager is set with a ConnectionString Property with the whole connection string contained in my ConStr Variable as expression (@[User::ConStr]). 
Error message is : Failed to acquire connection "Source" conenction may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions ...

I don't know why I am not able to connect to apply the query to the different databases. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that connection string will work on all the servers with the appropriate values swapped in?  It may be worth looking at something like [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/) to automate the creation of several packages rather than trying to do everything in the one.

Comment: Yes sure, for the moment I only have one server and 3dbs to connect to.

Comment: Have you outputted each generated connection string, hardcoded each and checked to see if that works?

Comment: I fond the solution, there were a mismatch in the Foreach loop to fill the ConStr variable. Once I have this working, is it possible to use the connection string in a DataFlow task instead of a SQL transact ?

Comment: You would use the connection string in the Connection Manager and then set up your tasks in the data flow to use that connection.

Comment: Sure, that is what I have done  but as the connection is in offline mode, I cannot bind the fields in the dataflow.

Comment: When you ask a question of people that don't have access to your set up Owen,  you need to include the relevant contextual details otherwise you are just wasting everyone's time.  I would recommend you follow the link to Biml I provided earlier rather than trying to make a 'one size fits all' package.